# Grails Filters index from one controller but not another

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working on an app that uses a filter currently.  I need to add to it, the AssetsController.  currently the filter looks like:

```
def filters {
    excludeSomeActionsOnSomeController(controller: 'foo', action: 'actionA|actionB', invert: true) {
        ...Filter work done here
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `url: '/assets/*'`, restarted the application, but the filter still fired for the AssetController.

My problem here is I want to also match any hit to the AssetsController so that it is also excluded.  I do not want to exclude the index method from FooController, just actionA and actionB.

Is there a way to do this built in, or will I need to add some logic inside the filter?

### Edit

What this filter is doing is logging to the database each request.  We currently run it for every request except actionA & actionB on FooController.  I'm converting from the resources plugin to the asset-pipeline plugin and noticed every call to an asset is now getting logged (we don't want/care about this data).

Right now I'm using the following as a work-around, but I'm looking for a better solution.

```
def filters {
    excludeSomeActionsOnSomeController(controller: 'foo', action: 'actionA|actionB', invert: true) {
        if (controllerName != 'assets') {
            ...Filter work done here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... When do you want to run this filter? Please, provide specific example when you want and don't want to execute it. Tx!